# MSSQL Trigger - Updating newly inserted record on INSERT

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert, last-insert-id

I wish to make a modification (Set Deleted = 1) to rows being inserted into my table `CustomerContact` if the `SELECT` statement returns more than 0.

I have the following, but it remains untested:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mark_cust_contact_deleted ON CustomerContact
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @numrows INT;

    /* Determine if order matches criteria for marking customer contact as DELETED immediately */
    SELECT @numrows = COUNT(*)
    FROM [Order] o
    JOIN OrderMeterDetail om
          ON o.OrderID = om.OrderID
    WHERE o.WorkTypeID = 3 AND o.WorkActionID = 26 AND o.WorkStageID IN (109, 309, 409)
    AND om.MeterDetailTypeID = 1 AND om.MeterLocationID IN (2, 4)
    AND o.orderid IN (SELECT OrderID FROM INSERTED);

    /* If the order matches the criteria, mark the customer contact as deleted */
    IF (@numrows >= 1)

        UPDATE CustomerContact
        SET Deleted = 1
        WHERE CustomerContactID IN (SELECT CustomerContactID FROM INSERTED);

END
```

Within my `IF` statement, I am using `FROM INSERTED`, assuming that this will return the **newly inserted id** for the record that was created by the insert.

I have two questions about this statement:

- Will this part of the statement perform an `UPDATE` just the record
  that was just inserted into `CustomerContact`?

  `UPDATE CustomerContact
             SET Deleted = 1
             WHERE CustomerContactID IN (SELECT CustomerContactID FROM INSERTED);`
- Is this the way that would be deemed correct to make a change to a row that has just been inserted based on the result of a `SELECT` statement?

`CustomerContactID` is an auto-incrementing primary key column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say "Just the record that was inserted". `Inserted` can contain more than one record. If there is only one, then your trigger will function as you expect. But if there is more than one, it won't.

I would rewrite your logic into a single `update` statement along the lines of...

```
 Update CustomerContact
 Set Deleted = 1
 From CustomerContact
       inner join inserted on CustomerContact.CustomerContactID = inserted.CustomerContactID
       inner join orders on inserted.OrderID = orders.OrderID
 where
     -- some criteria.
```

Comment: Is there a way to perform the trigger for each row?

Comment: Can you explain why the original try of OP would not work if there were multiple rows inserted? I do not see it, hes setting `@numrows` where `o.orderid IN (SELECT OrderID FROM INSERTED)`  looking for `IF (@numrows >= 1)` and updates `WHERE CustomerContactID IN (SELECT CustomerContactID FROM INSERTED)` where would it fail exactly? Of couse your syntax using `JOIN`s is more beautiful ;)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste Because if one record matches the `where` criteria, then all the records will be marked as deleted, as opposed to only the ones that match the criteria.

Comment: @podiluska Thank you so much for your help.  I have posted a potential solution.  I'd appreciate if you could give it a quick look to see what you think, right/wrong?  :)

Comment: @Coulton It looks more or less right, but without knowing your data structures, I can't be sure. I would remove the `AND o.OrderID = i.CustomerContactID` from the where clause and move it to the appropriate join.

Comment: I just did that just before you commented :).  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER mark_cust_contact_deleted ON CustomerContact
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @numrows INT;

    /* Determine if order matches criteria for marking customer contact as DELETED immediately */
    -- Get all the records into a temp table 
    SELECT * INTO #Temp
    FROM inserted
    Declare @ID int;

    SELECT @numrows = COUNT(*)
    FROM [Order] o
    JOIN OrderMeterDetail om
          ON o.OrderID = om.OrderID
    WHERE o.WorkTypeID = 3 AND o.WorkActionID = 26 AND o.WorkStageID IN (109, 309, 409)
    AND om.MeterDetailTypeID = 1 AND om.MeterLocationID IN (2, 4)
    AND o.orderid IN (SELECT OrderID FROM #Temp);
 IF (@numrows >= 1)
  BEGIN
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #Temp)
    BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 1 @ID = ID FROM #Temp


    /* If the order matches the criteria, mark the customer contact as deleted */


        UPDATE CustomerContact
        SET Deleted = 1
        WHERE CustomerContactID IN (SELECT CustomerContactID FROM #Temp WHERE ID = @ID);

        DELETE FROM #Temp WHERE ID = @ID
    END
  END   
     DROP TABLE #Temp
END
```

I think you can do something like this, tweak the code to futher suit for needs, hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to look at my problem! +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution that I used to solve this issue:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mark_cust_contact_deleted ON CustomerContact
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE CustomerContact
    SET Deleted = 1
    FROM CustomerContact cc
        JOIN inserted i
            ON cc.CustomerContactID = i.CustomerContactID
        JOIN [Order] o
            ON i.OrderID = o.OrderID
        JOIN OrderMeterDetail om
            ON i.OrderID = om.OrderID
    WHERE o.WorkTypeID = 3 AND o.WorkActionID = 26 AND o.WorkStageID IN (109, 309, 409)
    AND om.MeterDetailTypeID = 1 AND om.MeterLocationID IN (2, 4)

END
```